# Way to share task and results between Azure website and workers

Tags: azure, architecture

We need to change our system to a two-tiered structure on azure with an Azure website handling requests and adding tasks to a queue which will then be processed in priority order by a set of Azure worker roles. The website will then return the results to the end user. The data and results sets for each task will be largish (several megabytes). What's the best way to broker this exchange of data.

We could do it via an Azure storage blob but they are quite slow. Is there a better way? Up until now we have been doing everything in scaled azure website which allows all instances access to the same disk.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a long-running process I doubt that using blob storage would add that much overhead, although you don't specify what the tasks are.

On [Zudio](http://zud.io) long-running tasks update Table Storage tables with progress and completion status, and we use polling from the browser to check when a task has finished. In the case of a large result returning to the user, we provide a direct link with a shared access signature to the blob with the completion message, so they can download it directly from storage. We're looking at replacing the polling with SignalR running over Service Bus, and having the worker roles send updates directly to the client, but we haven't started that development work yet so I can't tell you how that will actually work.

Comment: Thanks. We were thinking something similar. FYI we tried moving to SignalR running ServiceBus and we ended up having to pull it because we hit a show-stopper bug. May have been fixed by now though.